# Visual Studio - Visual C++ UI error after addid cURL library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curl, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Hi im recently coding a little launcher which is connected with database (for login purposes) and after this I would like to download a file from a server so I included cURL. But after including cURL and following the tutorial I have a problem with editing an UI's. My App has 2 forms one for login then opens a second one if logged succesfully.

[When I opens the UI edit tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KshP5.png)

[I installed an cURL library with this Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eu7NFeg43T4&t=431s)

Comment: Not enough information. Can you show us the data of call stack?

Comment: @Asesh http://i.imgur.com/twaThsE.png It happened right after including the library and changing some solution proporties following the tutorial